# React-Table V7 Get button states in the same row

Tags: reactjs, react-table, react-table-v7

I have a simple table with two buttons in each row.

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-wind-v5v0y1?file=/src/App.js)

What I need to do is to make the state of each button visible to each other in each row. Essentially Button Col 1 - 0 knows if Button Col 2 - 0 is clicked or not and vice versa. I am trying to make this happen by making a local row state. However I am not sure how to do this in react-table v7. I am reading the docs and there seems to be a `useRowState` I am having trouble understanding on how to customize it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating a global context consisting the state of each button (in an array etc). This way you can know in any button which other button was clicked using useEffect.